# What is a realistic look for a humanoid race that can live in deep-water and land?

Tags: magic, underwater, species

So I have an original species that I'm creating called the Larimar. I have a picture of them below, which I drew. I'm still working on the backstory for these folks, and I don't want to give away too much but heres a little info on them.

There are a number of underwater cities that have been there a very long time. Before the Larimar, although some do visit these ruins.  There are great tunnels, made of a durable, phosphorescent material (which looks like crystal, but I'm playing with the idea of it being bone of a celestial creature). These tunnels are so strong, that they can withstand the pressure of deep sea.

The Larimar will live within these tunnels, as well as hunt from the few areas that allow them to meld into the deep sea waters (by magic of course). They are an amiable race, who interacts with land dwellers. Sometimes in these tunnels, sometimes on land.

The big question is this: **I know of only a few species that can travel into the depths of the ocean, and then be able to come up, and survive at the waters edge, where us humans live. If my species was able to do this, what appearance would be more likely if they were once land dwellers? (humanoid)**

I hope that is clear enough of an edit to reopen as I am very interested in hearing peoples answers.

[image: depiction of a Larimar]

Comment: you are asking two very different questions in one. Please split them.

Comment: By the very use of the magic tag, you can make them do whatever you want.

Comment: Nice deep sea humanoid!

Comment: What is the point of the crystal-like tunnels to these creatures?  If there is any way to pass from the inside to the outside, then the water pressure will collapse any atmosphere in the tunnel until it is the same pressure as outside.  It would be a lot of effort for them to create depressurized tunnels with decompression chamber entryways, and if they can withstand the pressure anyway then there's no need.

Comment: I feel like on some level you want an explanation for why a humanoid creature would go from being land-dwelling all the way to becoming a deep sea critter, which is basically just asking "how would X evolve" while still probably wanting to keep the design or at least general aesthetic of it you have now. Even reworded, this is just way too broad, especially since you seem to want this overlap of science and magic in your world, but you've done little to explain how they interact and where one begins and the other ends, which we NEED to know. I'd recommend Sandboxing this one for a while.